# [iOS][Objective-c] imagepicker to next controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

```
- (IBAction)sendPhoto:(id)sender {
    [DinsowMiniLogger log:@"Image: %@", self.pickedImage];
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[self navigationController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.selMediaItem = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectmedia"];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.selMediaItem animated:YES];
    self.selMediaItem.imgMediaSelect.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

I want to send image to next controller but error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   imgMediaSelect]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15979a00'

**UPDATE
i move uiimagepickercontroller method to next controller**

Comment: could you please show where you have defined imgMediaSelect?

Comment: just define a property of UIImage in your next view controller and then assign your image here  self.selMediaItem.imageProperty=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];   then you have image in your next viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method should be like below. You are dismissing your view before you perform any action.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *browsed_Image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       if (browsed_Image) {
           // You can store here your image in UIImage object or directly pass it to next controller.
           [btn_UserImage setImage:browsed_Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }];
}
```